# Spark : How to merge the transformations

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, rdd

I have 1000 json files, i need to do some transformations on each of the file, and then create a merged output file, which can have overlapping operations on values, (for example, say, it should not have repeated values)

So, if i read the files as `wholeTextFiles`, as a `title,content` pair, and then in the `map` function, i parse the `content` as `json tree` and perform the transformation, where and how do i merge the output?

Do i need to have another transform on the resultant RDD's to merge the values, and how would this work? Can i have a shared object(a List or a Map or RDD(?)) amongst all map blocks, which will be updated as part of the transformation, so that i can check for repeated values there?

P.S: Even if the output creates part files, i would still like to have no repititions.

Code:

```
//read the files as JavaPairRDD , which gives <filename, content> pairs
String filename = "/sample_jsons";
JavaPairRDD<String,String> distFile = sc.wholeTextFiles(filename);

//then create a JavaRDD from the content.
JavaRDD<String> jsonContent = distFile.map(x -> x._2);

//apply transformations, the map function will return an ArrayList which would
//have property names.

JavaRDD<ArrayList<String>> apm = jsonContent.map(
                new Function< String, ArrayList<String> >() {
                            @Override
                            public ArrayList<String> call(String arg0) throws Exception {

                                JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(arg0);
                                return parseJsonAndFindKey(rootNode, "type", "rootParent");
                            }
                });
```

So, this way i am able to get all first level properties in an `ArrayList`, from each json file.

Now i need a final `ArrayList`, as a union of all these arraylists, removing duplicates. How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need 1000 RDDs for 1000 json files?

Do you see any issue with merging the 1000 json files in the input stage into one RDD?

If you'll be using one RDD from the input stage, it shouldn't be hard to perform all the needed actions on this RDD.

Comment: 1000 just represents a big number, it can be lacs

Comment: okay. do you see any problem with reading the entire directory of files into one input RDD?

Comment: If I read as entire text files, it will give me one rdd for each text file, if I create a single rdd for the whole directory (not sure how to do that) then would it still be possible to manipulate each record in parallel, how would I specify the transform function

Comment: can you please update your question to include the relevant code you are currently using to read the json files?